# Azure B2C Postman OAuth 2.0 - Implicit Grant - invalid_request

Tags: postman, azure-ad-b2c

I have Postman set up following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-postman-to-get-a-token-and-test-the-api

When I attempt to get new Access Token, Postman prompts a window with my B2C Sign in page.

I then attempt to sign in, however receive the following error in Postman: Error `invalid_request`

There is no other additional details. I feel I've followed the guide exactly.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Hi @aherrick Does the callback URL in the Postman window match the reply URL for the application registration in the Azure AD B2C tenant?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett thanks for the response. Yes the callback URL is one of a few different URLs I have registered under the app. I’ve tried a few of them and they all fail

Comment: I tried on my side, it works well. Have you checked your Scope if it has the right api id uri?

Comment: Hi @aherrick, did you ever find a resolution to this or what was causing the issue? I'm experiencing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the request, you need to make sure the callback url same with your app reply url and api id uri of the `Scope` same with your API in the B2C.

The request is:

[image]

And the result like this:

[image]